# How to pass the values from one page to other in android?

Tags: android

In my application I passed the values from page1 to page2 and it is working fine. Now I want to send those values not only from page1 to page2 but also to page3. How can I do that? Please help me regarding this....

Page1

```
public static final String CATEGORY_KEY = "category";

btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Page1.this,
                        Page2.class);
                myIntent.putExtra(CATEGORY_KEY, "10");
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

            }
});
btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Page1.this,
                        Page2.class);
                myIntent.putExtra(CATEGORY_KEY, "11");
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

            }
        });
```

Page2

```
public static String catgryid;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


       ImageView type=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

       Intent intent = getIntent();
       catgryid = intent.getStringExtra(Page1.CATEGORY_KEY);


            if(catgryid.trim().equals("10"))
            { 

                type.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img1);
            }

            else if(catgryid.trim().equals("11"))
            { 

                type.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img2);
            }
}
```

Comment: it is not coming.. you mean you are getting null values?on doing same as in page 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use any of these for it

- A singleton pattern to share the date across multiple non-consecutive activities.
- A shared preference.
- An external storage
- Entry into db.
- passing data with intents.

This link will give you some more details:

http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/framework.html#3